# How to make ImageView fill vertically within RelativeLayout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I put an `ImageView` and a `TextView` within a `RelativeLayout` that is used as list items, and want the `ImageView` to grow vertically with the line number of `TextView`. The drawable of the `ImageView` is a *png* picture of vertical bar.

With the following layout, thought it looks fine in the Layout view in Eclipse, the `ImageView` does not fill the height of the `RelativeView` at run-time. Instead, it always keeps the original picture's height.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:src="@drawable/vbar"
       android:adjustViewBounds="false"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:singleLine="false"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Why does it not work as I expect *(or as shown in Eclipse Layout view)*?

Comment: If you use `android:background` instead of `android:src` does it change anything?

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in your code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/tv"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now it is giving proper output.
What I did is, declared textview first and aligned it to parent bottom. Then declared imageview and alogned it on textview's top. So imageview will start just above the textview and take all remaining height. I have tested for multiline textview, too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I would do a couple of things:

1. Simplify the layout by combining the TextView with a "drawableLeft".
2. Make the image a 9-patch image so it grows accordingly.